# Unable to pass updated state using react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

```
    const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState("");
    
    const getMinDate = () =>{
     if(endDate ==="")
        return "02/03/2020";
    else 
        return "10/10/2020";
    }

const selectStartDate = (value) =>{
setEndDate(value)
}
    
    return (<>
    <Select onChange={selectStartDate} />
    <Calendar min-date={getMinDate()}/>
    </>)
```

> Im trying to change min-date params each time Select value changes as
> shown in the code but the value for min-date doesnt change on each
> time change

Comment: Can you provide some debugging details. If you console log from within `getMinDate` can you see that it is being called as expected? Is the correct condition being entered? Etc..

Answer (score 0):

An onChange method should return an `event`, you can then parse the value using `event.target.value` within your selectStateDate function.

```
const selectStartDate = (event) => setEndDate(event.target.value);
```